# how to concatenate uniqueidentifier in a dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I have a dynamic query in which I want to concatenate uniqueidentifier, but + and & operators are not supporting this, is there a way I can concatenate uniqueidentifier to a dynamic string. Any sample or any help in this regard will be highly appricated.

Answer (score 20):

Have you tried casting or converting to a string first, then concating?

```
CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(36))
```

Comment: i tried this it is not working, giving incorrect syntax near cast, or convert if im converting

Comment: @Yaser: "SELECT CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(36))". Please try and think for yourself.

Comment: Sorry Dear friends my where condition is 
WHERE (CreatedBy= CAST(@p_CreatedBy AS NVARCHAR(100)) )
here @CreatedBy is a uniqueidentifier
i even tried converting it, not getting any result.
Please help

Comment: @Yaser CAST() may be formatting the Guid differently than your "CreatedBy" column. Run both versions by hand and check that the strings follow the same format. If not, then convert the other "CreatedBy" to a Guid and compare Guids instead.

Comment: it might be the problem, but how do i do that

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old but I ran into this post trying to figure out the same thing and the problem was that I didn't have enough 's around my unique identifier.  I basically had:

`'SELECT * FROM Interface WHERE ID = '' + CAST(@InterfaceID AS NVARCHAR(36)) + '' AND 1 = 1'`

I got an error saying incorrect syntax near 00A (the first part of the GUID).  The problem is that this was parsing to :

`SELECT * FROM Interface WHERE ID = 00A3F5B5-C7B3-4128-B03A-EADE79129F40 AND 1 = 1`

By changing my query to:

`'SELECT * FROM Interface WHERE ID = ''' + CAST(@InterfaceID AS NVARCHAR(36)) + ''' AND 1 = 1'`

with three apostrophes I got:

`SELECT * FROM Interface WHERE ID = '00A3F5B5-C7B3-4128-B03A-EADE79129F40' AND 1 = 1`

Which is correct.

Hope that helps.